# Using sed or vi to add sequential number to the end of a line in a file

Tags: regex, vim, vi

all!
I am trying to update a file with new IP addresses, and I need to learn how to add sequential number to the end of a file, but not beginning with 1.

For example, if I do this in vi:

```
:%s/^/\=line('.')/
```

I get:

```
192.168.44.1
192.168.44.2
192.168.44.3
...
```

But I want this:

```
192.168.44.38
192.168.44.39
192.168.44.40
...
```

I can't figure out how to get it to start with a number > 1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
:let i=38 | g/$/s//\=i/ | let i=i+1
```

It finds end of each line and adds the `i` value, initialized as `38`. The value of `i` is incremented each time the match is found with `let i=i+1`.

Mind that the pipe in `| let i=i+1` belongs to the `g//` command, that is why it is executed for all lines.

Answer (score 0):

just add 37:

```
:%s/^/\=line('.')+37/
```